# Почему не передается json объект на сервер с node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Коллеги, добрый день.
Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?
Есть сервак во вне, у него есть директория /user
Я хочу скормить ему json объект, а потом через веб интерфейс посмотреть, что пользователь создался, но когда вбиваю в браузер [http://(ip-сервера)/user/Victor](http://(ip-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0)/user/Victor) , то мне выдается ошибка в браузере - error   "Пользователь не найден".

Вот собственно код (в коде userResponse - это тупо DIV с IDшником, куда должен приходить ответ от сервера):

```
//функция-конструктор для создания пользователей
function Users(name, email, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.age = age;
};
//тупо созданный пользователь, которого пробуем через POST отправить на сервер
  var user1 = new Users('Victor', 'viccctor@mail.ru', 33);
  user1 = JSON.stringify(user1);

//функция отправки нового  пользователя на сервер
const sendNewUser = () => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', `${baseURL}/user/`, true);
  xhr.send(user1);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      userResponse.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
  };
};

sendNewUser();
```